# high availability singleton processor in Tomcat

Tags: java, high-availability

I have a job processing analytic service working against RDBMS that, due to the need for complex caching and cache update logic needs to be a singleton in a high availability cluster. Jobs are coming as JMS messages (via ActiveMQ). It is part of the application hosted in HA Tomcat cluster with web front end.

The problem is, the service itself needs to be able to recover within seconds if a node where it is running fails. Failure could mean system down or just a slow CPU - i.e. if node recovers after CPU delay, but the processing is handed over, it cannot continue.

From experience, what would be the most suitable solution here:

- database-based locks and lock checking before each job starts (I could not easily come up with bullet-proof solution here - any recommendations?)
- some kind of Paxos algorithm? Do you know of any slim framework for that purpose as the algorithm itself takes time to get right and then QA?
- anything else?

I don't mind if failure recovery is slow, but I would want to minimize an overhead for each job.

Some additional background: job does not involve anything more than reading data from the database, massaging it with various algorithms (somewhat resembling finding shortest routes) and putting back optimal solutions for different actors to move on. Actors interact with real world and put back some feedback, based on which consequent steps are optimized by the same job processor.

Comment: Maybe distributed locks in [tag:hazelcast]?

Comment: Just to clarify: one node in the cluster executes the 'singleton' job, all others are in 'slave' mode? In case one node fails, another node has to recover the jobs' state and proceed with execution?

Comment: @home: correct. In terms of the service, N-1 nodes are in slave mode. They are serving web pages in load-balanced manner, but not processing jobs.

Comment: There is of course HASingleton in JBoss, but I would like something a little more lightweight.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz: it is an interesting approach, thanks. If I come up with the need or at least a good usage for distributed cache in my case, I will consider it (or ehcache).

Comment: @AlexPakka What did you do in the end?

Comment: @alexvetter - I am working on hazelcast-based solution. I will post an answer as soon as I get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution Using Hazelcast

Hazelcast locking method proposed by Tomasz works. You need to [read documentation carefully](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/lock.html), use time leased locks and ensure monitoring of your singleton to renew leases. One thing to keep in mind is that Hazelcast was written to work in large clusters - as such its start up time is relatively slow, 1 to 5 seconds even for two nodes. But after that operations are qute performant and obtainng the lock takes milliseconds. Normally it all does not matter, but failure/recovery cycle takes time and it should be treated as exceptional situation.

There are limits to this solution being buletproof. If the cluster is split (network disruption between nodes) but each node is alive and has access to the database, there is no way of knowing deterministically how to proceed. Ultimately, you need to think about a contingency plan here. In real life this scenario is very unlikely for a typical failover HA setup.

At the end of the day, before resorting to a solution with distributed locking, think hard about making your process not-so-singleton. It might still be hard to run certain things in parallel, but it might not be so hard to ensure the cache is not stale or find other ways to prevent database corruption. In my case, there is a database transaction counter working like optimisitic lock. Code reads it before making all the decisions and update-where's it in both, db and cache in the transaction where the result is stored.  In case of discrepancy cache is purged and operation repeated. It makes two nodes working in parallel impossibly slow, but it prevents data corruption. By storing additional data with the transaction counter you might be able to optimize cache refresh strategies and slowly move towards parallel processing.

#### Conclusion.

This is how I would proceed about such a request next time.

1. Try making your singletons survive working in parallel on different nodes
2. Try again, maybe there is a way to orchestrate them
3. Check if it is possible to use HASingleton or similar technology to
   avoid boilerplate
4. Implement the Hazelcast solution as outlined above

It makes no sense to post the code here as the most time consuming part is to test and verify all failure scenarios and contingency plans. There is almost no boilerplate, the code itself will always be solution specific. It is possible to come up with well working PoC covering all the bases within couple of days.