# High availability in web application with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, web, microservices, high-availability

We are developing a web server which allows user to submit spark jobs to run a hadoop cluster, and the web server will help to create a new cluster and keep monitoring the job.

We deployed the web server in 3 nodes and put a loader balancer in front of them.
The High Availability requirement is that once user has submitted the job, there must be one server keep monitoring it, in case the server is done, then another server should take this task and monitoring the job, so that it has no any impact to user.

Is there any suggested way to do that? What I could think is put all job information to some central storage(a table in a database), and all server keep polling the job info from the table, using distributed lock to ensure there will be only one and always be one server lock each row in the table hence monitoring that job.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like hazelcast solution sounds ok.
[high availability singleton processor in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386495/high-availability-singleton-processor-in-tomcat?rq=1)

And still checking whether this is the best when doing in AWS.